# threads in pthread stop working after some iterations

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded code but I'm having a little problem.
In my program, I have two types of threads, explorers (which i have 4 or 5 of) and main (which I have one of). I want to all explorers threads run simultaneously, and when they're all done    main thread starts its job. there's a loop which i do above thing over and over. because of overhead of thread creating i decided to make explorers threads sleep while main is running and wake it when it's done (and of course vise versa ). In order to achieve this goal I used barriers. following is a pseudo-code of my threads:

main thread function:

```
void* main(void* arg)
{
     while(true)
     {
         wait_for_barrier_1

         do_your_job

         reset_barrier_1
         wait_for_barrier_2
     }
}
```

explorers thread function

```
void* explorers(void* arg)
{
     while(true)
     {

         do_your_job

         wait_for_barrier_1         

         if(thread_id == 0)
         {
             reset_barrier_2
         }             

         wait_for_barrier_2
     }
}
```

barrier_1 is used for preventing main run before ending explorers, and barrier_2 is used for preventing explorers before ending main.

My problem is this code don't work fully correct. At the beginning it works fine, but after two or three iteration some of explorer threads suddenly will stop working and so the whole program will stop working.

I can't figure it out, specially because there is no rule in number of iteration. In some runs it stops after first iteration, In some other it works fine until 5th or 6th one.

By the way i'm using Mac OSX.

Comment: We really need to see the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problems accure because when you reset a barrier it lost its memory and forget how meny threads reaches it before. so for example it's possible that explorer waits for Barrier1, then time goes to main, main pass Barrier1 do its job and reset it before explorer get a chance to pass it. so in this situation main is waiting for Barrier2 and explorer is waiting for Barrier1 (which is reseted by main)

In order to solve this problem I used two barrier variable for each barrier and switched between them in iterations. The following is my pseudo-code. It works totally fine.

main function:

```
void* main(void* arg)
{
     bool turn = false;

     while(true)
     {
         if(turn)
         {
             wait_for_barrier_1
         }
         else
         {
             wait_for_barrier_1_P
         }

         do_your_job

         if(turn)
         {
             reset_barrier_1_P
         }
         else
         {
             reset_barrier_1
         }

         if(turn)
         {
             wait_for_barrier_2
         }
         else
         {
             wait_for_barrier_2_P
         }

         turn = !turn ;
     }
}
```

explorer function:

```
void* main(void* arg)
{
     bool turn = false;

     while(true)
     {
         do_your_job

         if(turn)
         {
             reset_barrier_2
         }
         else
         {
             reset_barrier_2_P
         }

         if(turn)
         {
             wait_for_barrier_1
         }
         else
         {
             wait_for_barrier_1_P
         }


         if(turn)
         {
             wait_for_barrier_2
         }
         else
         {
             wait_for_barrier_2_P
         }

         turn = !turn ;
     }
}
```

I know it's a little messy, but it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Answering as best as I can without seeing the actual code, it seems possible that main is passing through wait_for_barrier_2 *before* the explorer thread has reset_barrier_2.

So main loops back around to wait_for_barrier_1, and *then* the explorer threads reset_barrier_2, and wait_for_barrier_2.  As such main waits for 1, explorers wait for 2, no one proceeds.

Something like this:

```
Iteration 1:
main wait_for_barrier_1
                        explorers do_your_job
                        explorers wait_for_barrier_1
main do_your_job
                        explorers reset_barrier_2
                        explorers wait_for_barrier_2
main reset_barrier_1
main wait_for_barrier_2
main wait_for_barrier_1…

Iteration 2:
…main wait_for_barrier_1
                        explorers do_your_job
                        explorers wait_for_barrier_1
main do_your_job
main reset_barrier_1
main wait_for_barrier_2 (but it hasn't been reset yet! Runs right through!)
main wait_for_barrier_1
                        explorers reset_barrier_2
                        explorers wait_for_barrier_2

Deadlock!
```

I think it might work if you reset_barrier_2 before you wait_for_barrier_1, that way main won't be able to rush through wait_for_barrier_2 before it is reset.

Comment: actually i had the same problem when I switched commands as you said. the problem was when you reset a barrier it forgot its last. So sometimes for example explorer is waiting for B1, then time goes to main, main do its job and reset B1, before explorer get the chance to pass it and ...
I solve my problem by using two barrier variable for each barrier and switch between them in iterations.

By the way thanks for the idea, it really encourage me to search for that kinds of deadlocks.